# Where does phonegap store database on android?

Tags: android, cordova, sqlite

I thought it should be at /data/data//databases/mydb.db,

but when I use adb, it cannot locate the database. The way I create db is:

```
db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
```

Interestingly, I have no problem accessing the db/creating tables from my code. But not DDMS or adb.

Answer (score 1):

From `window.openDatabase(...)` I assume this is javascript code and `window` is the browser window object. In this case you're *not* using Androids native SQLite database but the build in browser database supported by the mobile browser.

Therefore the database should be somewhere in the innards of the browser app and you can't access it via the adb.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine that. Saying the database is stored in the (likely default) browser you need to have access to that app's files and find the database file in particular. This probably requires a rooted phone and good understanding of the actual browser. Both not topics I'm familiar with. Also note if you solve the problem for one browser the user might use another one.